# How to render an array of document fragments?

Tags: javascript

```js
var fragment = [];

function create1() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    x = document.createElement('div');
    x.className = "di";
    x.textContent = 'Change background color';
    fragment[i] = document.createDocumentFragment();
    console.log(fragment[i]);
    fragment[i].append(x.cloneNode(true));
  }

  document.body.append(fragment);
}
create1();
```

```css
.di {
  border: solid green 2px;
  margin-right: 65em;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
```

I created an array of document fragment but I am unable to render them to the HTML DOM properly, please help

Comment: `fragment` is an array of fragments. `document.body.append(fragment);` won't work. You have to append element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make a lot of sense to create a `DocumentFragment` per element: a `DocumentFragment` can be very useful to collect multiple elements into a single group to append them all at once. Otherwise you could just append the element to the body directly without using the document fragment and get the same result. See the result below.

```js
function create1() {
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  const x = document.createElement('div');
  x.className = "di";
  x.textContent = 'Change background color';
    
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    fragment.append(x.cloneNode(true));
  }

  document.body.append(fragment);
}

create1();
```

```css
.di {
  border: solid green 2px;
  margin-right: 65em;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
```

Comment: TIL there is an `Element.append` method. I've only ever used `Element.appendChild`. Thanks :)

Comment: Your code now creates an element 5 times and also clones it 5 times. I would advise to move element creation outside the loop, and just clone 5 times.

Comment: @KooiInc ... yea ..So I rewrote as :
function create1() {
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
 const x = document.createElement('div');
    x.className = "di";
    x.textContent = 'Change background color';
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    fragment.append(x.cloneNode(true));
  }
  document.body.append(fragment);
}
create1();

Comment: @KooiInc good addition, I've added it to the snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Your `fragment` variable is an array, not a document node. You must spread the argument in the `append` call -

```js
var fragment = [];

function create1() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    x = document.createElement('div');
    x.className = "di";
    x.textContent = 'Change background color';
    fragment[i] = document.createDocumentFragment();
    fragment[i].append(x);
  }
  
  document.body.append(...fragment) // ✅ spread fragment
}

create1();
```

```css
.di {
  border: solid green 2px;
  margin-right: 65em;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
```

But don't stop there -

❌ leaked global variable `x`
❌ unnecessary global `fragment`
❌ functions don't take arguments or return values
❌ poor function composition, separate concerns

```js
function div(className = "", textContent = "") { // ✅ parameters
  const e = document.createElement("div")
  e.className = className
  e.textContent = textContent
  return e // ✅ use return value 
}

function fragment(...children) { // ✅ separate concerns
  const e = document.createDocumentFragment()
  e.append(...children)
  return e // ✅
}

function create(count = 0) { // ✅ use function parameters
  const fragments = [] // ✅ localize variables to functions
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    fragments.push(
      fragment(div("di", "change background color"))
    )
  }
  return fragments // ✅ use return values
}

document.body.append(...create(3)) // ✅ functions are flexible
```

```css
.di {
  border: solid green 2px;
  margin-right: 65em;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
```

I agree with @EmielZuurbier. It doesn't make sense to use fragments that contain a single child. It would be better to either append each `div` to the body directly or append all divs to a fragment and finally append the single fragment to the body. Here's what that would look like -

```js
function div(className = "", textContent = "") {
  const e = document.createElement("div")
  e.className = className
  e.textContent = textContent
  return e
}

function fragment(...children) { 
  const e = document.createDocumentFragment()
  e.append(...children)
  return e
}

function create(count = 0) {
  const divs = [] // ✅ array of divs
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    divs.push(
      div("di", "change background color")
    )
  }
  return fragment(...divs) // ✅ return single fragment
}

document.body.append(create(3)) // ✅ append single fragment
```

```css
.di {
  border: solid green 2px;
  margin-right: 65em;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I'm not sure you'll need an array here</strike>. Here's a utility function creating and appending `[n]` elements (using a shorter syntax for element creation) to `document.body`.

```js
function create1(n) {
  const elem = Object.assign(
    document.createElement(`div`),
    { className: `di`, textContent: `change background color` } );
  const elems = Array.from({length: n}, _ => elem.cloneNode(true));  
  document.body.append(...elems);
}
create1(5);
```

```css
.di {
  border: solid green 2px;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
```

Comment: createDocumentFragment() reduces page reflow as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment hence i went for that approach

Comment: @Richard. That's right. In that case ... see edited answer.

Comment: you could use `Array.from({length: n}, _ => …)` which creates one array instead of `...[...Array(n)].map(_ => …)` which creates 3 arrays. maybe it would help hard to read double spread too. just an idea.

Comment: @Mulan Sure, see edits.

Comment: Please explain your code syntax:  const elems = Array.from({length: n}, _ => elem.cloneNode(true));

Comment: @Richard It creates an array with n elements (in other words an `Array Object` with property `length: n`) and adds content to each of the elements using a callback function (aka lambda). In this case an in memory created element is cloned n times.
`[...Array(n)].map(_ => elem.cloneNode(true)))` would do the same.